# OSX Mavericks not downloading from Mac App Store (Lion)

Tags: upgrade, macos

I have OSX Lion 10.7.5 and am trying to download the new OSX Mavericks. 
There is free upgrade option in the Mac App store, which I click and it starts downloading on the launchpad.
But when first when I went to the Purchases section of the App store, the button against the OSX Mavericks said Download. 
When I click on it, nothing happened. 
In the launchpad it just keeps saying Downloading without much progress.

Any idea as to what could be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to just be patient. I had the same issue, I repeatedly clicked "Download" in the App Store, and in the Launchpad I couldn't see much progress at first, but eventually it was downloading (without me having to do anything and insanely clicking probably didn't help). It might take a couple of hours, as heaps of people are downloading at the moment.

Comment: I had this experience as well. The only place to see the download progress was Launchpad, which has a very tiny progress bar. I used the Network Activity section of Activity Monitor to verify that I was actually downloading something. Once it finished, the Mavericks installer popped up.

Comment: Actually I had left the download overnight.. But once I saw it again in the morning, the machine was off..